# How to convert MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: php, jquery, date

I have a jquery calendar that sets the input value to MM/DD/YYYY

How would I convert it so that my database column (date) can accept it correctly?

EDIT

Gordon was right - his link pointed me to this answer

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($user_date));
```

Comment: Is there really no [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+convert+MM%2FDD%2FYYYY+to+YYYY-MM-DD%3F+php) that would give you that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most jQuery plugins can be configured, even their date format.

Comment: Another option is to leave as is and let the DB do the conversion

Comment: Do it with SQL statement: INSERT INTO table (datecol) VALUES(date_format($YOURJQUERYDATE, '%m/%d/%Y'));

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
$date = "07/12/2010";
$your_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

I hope my answer is useful :)

Comment: It's important to note the different interpretation of `-` and `/` in the date.  If you use a `-` php will determine it to be DD-MM, if you use a `/` php will determine it to be MM-DD.

Comment: Just a note on @Devon comment, I did not know that PHP acted this way and, in my opinion, it is really a bad way to act, since it will lead to errors because there are places (like Brazil) where the date format is "DD/MM/YYYY" and because `/` is being used PHP will determine **wrongly** it to be "MM-DD".

Comment: @MuriloGarcia it's not really a fault of PHP.  strtotime() is a shortcut/helper function, if you decide to use the shortcut, you need to know what formats it accepts.  It can't possibly support an input of every possible date format because different formats conflict.  In the United States, it is MM/DD/YYYY, so it's impossible for strtotime to know when you enter 10/12/2017 that you mean December 10th versus October 12th...  You can use DateTime::createFromFormat() to create dates from any possible format or you can adhere to the formats that strtotime accepts.

Answer (score 14):

You want to do this in PHP, right?

1. Use Explode

   ```
   $christmas = "12/25/2010";
   $parts = explode('/',$christmas);
   $yyyy_mm_dd = $parts[2] . '-' . $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1]
   ```
2. Use `strptime` to parse it to a timestamp and then `strftime` to format it the way you want it.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code,

```
<?php
$date = "10/24/2014";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y" , $date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Comment: I liked this answer because it is more flexible, since PHP has not to guess anything, you are passing the date formats from (m/d/Y) and to (Y-m-d).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$date = explode('/', '16/06/2015');

$new  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(implode('-', array_reverse($date))));
```

Returns: 2015-06-15 00:00:00

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**We need more information?**

1) What script is inserting into database? I am assuming PHP

2) Also we need to know how you are storing the date and in what format?

My solution would be:

```
$dates = preg_split('/\//',$_POST['date']);

$month = $dates[0];
$day = $dates[1];
$year = $dates[2];

$finalDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

Comment: A `preg_` function call with a lone, static character in the pattern is avoidably inefficient.  I do not recommend that anyone implement this technique in any project for any reason.  There are better ways.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do this without using the `explode`:

```
$date = "12/25/2010";
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

You can now use `$mysql_date` to insert into your database.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use `strtotime()` function and then `date()`. By this you can convert any format of date.

```
$unix_time_stamp = strtotime($mm_dd_yyyy);
$yyyy_mm_dd = date(Y/m/d,$unix_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want one line try this:

```
$time = "07/12/2010";

$new_time = preg_replace("!([01][0-9])/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})!", "$3-$1-$2", $time);

var_dump($time);
var_dump($new_time);
```